Finite dimensional $l^p$ Norm is logarithmically convex.
I am working trough this book, where in lemma 1.6 (proof left to the reader), the asked to show that the map $p \mapsto \log \|X\|_{p,J}^p$ is convex. Here $\|X\|_{p,J}$ is the $p$-variation of a continuous path for $p \geq 1$.
To show this, it should be sufficient to show that the for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the map $p \mapsto \log\|x\|_p^p$ is convex, where $\|x\|_p = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p\right)^{\frac1p}$.
However, I cannot seem to figure out how to show this, simply differentiating twice did not work (the expression got two complicated, as far as I can see it).
Can someone give me a hint on how to start proving the above statement? Any link or reference would also be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

I think differentiating twice works: Of course you can ignore coordinates of $x$ which are $0$, so one has to show that if $a_1,\dots,a_n >0$, then
$$
f:[1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}, \quad f(p):= \log(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^p) 
$$
is convex. Now
$$
f'(p)= \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \log(a_k)a_k^p}{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^p},
$$
$$
f''(p)=\frac{(\sum_{k=1}^n (\log(a_k))^2a_k^p)(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^p)-(\sum_{k=1}^n \log(a_k)a_k^p)^2}{(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^p)^2}
$$
Thus $f''(p) \ge 0$ means that the numerator is $\ge 0$, which follows from CSI:
$$
(\sum_{k=1}^n \log(a_k)a_k^p)^2 = (\sum_{k=1}^n (\log(a_k)\sqrt{a_k^p})\sqrt{a_k^p})^2 \le (\sum_{k=1}^n (\log(a_k))^2a_k^p)(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^p).
$$

Thanks, nice answer. I guess missed that.

Let $p_t := tp_1+(1-t)p_2$, $p_i \ge 1$, $t \in (0,1)$.
Enough to show
$$\Big(\sum_{i = 1}^{n}|x_i|^{p_t}\Big)^{\frac{1}{p_t}} \le \Big(\sum_{i = 1}^{n}|x_i|^{p_1}\Big)^{\frac{t}{p_1}} \Big(\sum_{i = 1}^{n}|x_i|^{p_2}\Big)^{\frac{1-t}{p_2}}~.$$
We will use induction on $n$, the dimension of the space.
Trivially true for $n = 1$.
The induction step is as follows
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 1}^{k+1}|x_i|^{p_t} 
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{k}|x_i|^{p_t}+|x_{k+1}|^{p_t}\\
&\overset{\text{true for}~ k}{\le}\Bigg(\Big( \sum_{i = 1}^{k}|x_i|^{p_1}\Big)^{\frac{t}{p_1}} \Big( \sum_{i = 1}^{k}|x_i|^{p_2}\Big)^{\frac{1-t}{p_2}}\Bigg)^{p_t}+|x_{k+1}|^{p_t}\\
&\le\Bigg(\Big( \sum_{i = 1}^{k}|x_i|^{p_1}\Big)^{\frac{t}{p_1}} \Big( \sum_{i = 1}^{k}|x_i|^{p_2}\Big)^{\frac{1-t}{p_2}}+|x_{k+1}|\Bigg)^{p_t}
\end{align}
Thus,
\begin{align}
\Big(\sum_{i = 1}^{k+1}|x_i|^{p_t}\Big)^{\frac{1}{p_t}} &\le \Bigg(\Big( \sum_{i = 1}^{k}|x_i|^{p_1}\Big)^{\frac{t}{p_1}}+|x_{k+1}|^t \Bigg) \Bigg(\Big( \sum_{i = 1}^{k}|x_i|^{p_2}\Big)^{\frac{1-t}{p_2}}+|x_{k+1}|^{1-t}\Bigg)\\
&\le \Big( \sum_{i = 1}^{k+1}|x_i|^{p_1}\Big)^{\frac{t}{p_1}}~ \Big( \sum_{i = 1}^{k+1}|x_i|^{p_2}\Big)^{\frac{1-t}{p_2}}~,
\end{align}
as required.
